# If I copy a creature spell and it resolves, is the new permanent a token?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I copy a creature spell while it is on the stack, and then this copy resolves, I will get a creature object on my battlefield. Is this object a token? Or is it a nontoken object that happens to not have a physical card associated to it?

Comment: Wizards added the ability to copy permanent spells?  Boy do I feel old.

Comment: @Zags Before doing some research to find the answer, I was pretty sure the answer was going to be "it's not possible to copy a permanent spell; so the question is moot".

Comment: [Ertai's Meddling](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4698)

Comment: Or more recently, [Lithoform Engine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=491896)

Comment: @GendoIkari odd that they errattaed Ertai's to copy the original spell, the original wording of it puts the card back on the stack after the delay (a la suspend)

Comment: @Andrew Well the original wording doesn't really make any sense with modern Magic rules... it never removed it from the stack at all; in fact it does nothing to prevent the spell from resolving as normal! By putting the card on the stack as a copy of the original spell, it is retaining all choices made for that spell such as targets, modes, casting costs, etc. Using "copy" is the only way within the rules to achieve that; if you just re-cast it instead then you could make different choices.

Comment: @Andrew Also note that the Oracle wording does put the card itself back on the stack. It doesn't just create a copy to put on the stack; the card is put on the stack as a copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it becomes a token permanent.

> **706.10f** Some effects copy a permanent spell. As that copy resolves, it ceases being a copy of a spell and becomes a token permanent. (See rule 608.3b.)

> **608.3b** If the object that’s resolving is a copy of a permanent spell, that object becomes a token permanent and is put onto the battlefield under the control of the spell’s controller. It is no longer a copy of a spell. The token put onto the battlefield this way is not “created” for the purposes of any replacement effects or triggered abilities that refer to creating a token.

Note that this token copies all of the characteristics of the permanent spell that it copied, including mana cost, name, etc:

> **111.11.** A copy of a permanent spell becomes a token as it resolves. **The token has the characteristics of the spell that became that token.** The token is not “created” for the purposes of any replacement effects or triggered abilities that refer to creating a token.

> **109.3.** An object’s characteristics are name, mana cost, color, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, abilities, power, toughness, loyalty, hand modifier, and life modifier. Objects can have some or all of these characteristics.

Comment: It's probably worth adding here that the token has a non-zero CMC.  This confused me extensively when I first encountered this.

Comment: @John that's interesting, can you provide a source? GendoIkari can you add this fact to your answer please?

Comment: @PedroA Found it. It doesn't directly state anything about CMC, but says that it gets all characteristics of the permanent spell, and mana cost is a characteristic.

Comment: @PedroA, My source is MTG:Arena.  I was pretty shocked when I first saw it.  I'd just assumed it would be zero.